# QGIS Python - raster as point layer, coordinates issues

Tags: qgis, python, geometry

I would like to create point layer for storing values retrieved from a raster file.

My idea was to iterate through all raster cells. If cell value is different than NULL, I wish to create a new point which represent mentioned raster cell.

Unfortunately, result point layer, do not match raster data - points are far away from the raster file. After long time of investigation, I have still no idea what might be wrong. Could you help?

```
from osgeo import gdal
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsField, QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsFeature, QgsGeometry, QgsPoint

#read CRS as EPSG from the raster file:
myCRS = MyRasters['first'].crs().authid()
#read Raster path:
RasterfilePath=MyRasters['first'].dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
#Create temporary vector layer and add to map
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=" + myCRS, "temporary_points", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
# Add points:

pr = vl.dataProvider()

# Enter editing mode
vl.startEditing()

# add fields
pr.addAttributes( [ QgsField("first", QVariant.Double),
    QgsField("second",  QVariant.Int),
    QgsField("third", QVariant.Double) ] )

raster_or = gdal.Open(RasterfilePath)

nodata = raster_or.GetRasterBand(1).GetNoDataValue()
(upper_left_x, x_size, x_rotation, upper_left_y, y_rotation, y_size) = raster_or.GetGeoTransform()

numpy_array = raster_or.ReadAsArray()

width,height = numpy_array.shape
#width=raster_or.GetRasterBand(1).XSize
#height=raster_or.GetRasterBand(1).YSize

for row in range(0,width):
    for col in range(0,height):
        if  ~(nodata==numpy_array[row,col]):
            #Add new point:
            x = row * x_size + upper_left_x + (x_size / 2) #add half the cell size
            y = col * y_size + upper_left_y + (y_size / 2) #to centre the point
            # add a feature
            fet = QgsFeature()
            fet.setGeometry( QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(x,y )
            fet.initAttributes(3)
            fet.setAttribute(0, float(numpy_array[row,col]))
            pr.addFeatures( [ fet ] )
# Commit changes
vl.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Width and height are inverted (and there are other errors produced by bad copy/paste).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are inverted (width, height). Try this:

```
.
.
.

for row in range(height):
    for col in range(width):
.
.
.
```

**Editing Note:**

I edited your code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsField, QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsFeature, QgsGeometry, QgsPoint

#read CRS as EPSG from the raster file:
myCRS = iface.activeLayer().crs().authid()
#read Raster path:
RasterfilePath=iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
#Create temporary vector layer and add to map
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=" + myCRS, "temporary_points", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
# Add points:

pr = vl.dataProvider()

# Enter editing mode
vl.startEditing()

# add fields
pr.addAttributes( [ QgsField("first", QVariant.Double),
    QgsField("second",  QVariant.Int),
    QgsField("third", QVariant.Double) ] )

raster_or = gdal.Open(RasterfilePath)

nodata = raster_or.GetRasterBand(1).GetNoDataValue()
(upper_left_x, x_size, x_rotation, upper_left_y, y_rotation, y_size) = raster_or.GetGeoTransform()

numpy_array = raster_or.ReadAsArray()

#width,height = numpy_array.shape
width=raster_or.GetRasterBand(1).XSize
height=raster_or.GetRasterBand(1).YSize

# add a feature
fet = QgsFeature()

for row in range(height):
    for col in range(width):
        if  (nodata == numpy_array[row,col]):
#            #Add new point:
            x = col * x_size + upper_left_x + (x_size / 2) #add half the cell size
            y = row * y_size + upper_left_y + (y_size / 2) #to centre the point
            fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(x,y)))
            fet.initAttributes(3)
            fet.setAttribute(0, float(numpy_array[row,col]))
            fet.setAttribute(1, row)
            fet.setAttribute(2, col)
            pr.addFeatures( [ fet] )


# Commit changes
vl.commitChanges()
```

and I tested it by using a raster with nodata values:

[image]

It works! Points are in nodata values places.

Comment: Very nice! Always awesome to see people testing and reporting back, already gave you +1 =)

Comment: Thanks. The original code had some errors but now it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

And here is @xunilk's code translated to QGIS 3.*

```
from osgeo import gdal
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsField, QgsFeature, QgsGeometry, QgsPoint

#read CRS as EPSG from the raster file:
myCRS = iface.activeLayer().crs().authid()
#read Raster path:
RasterfilePath=iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
#Create temporary vector layer and add to map
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=" + myCRS, "temporary_points", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
# Add points:

# Enter editing mode
vl.startEditing()

# add fields
pr.addAttributes( [ QgsField("first", QVariant.Double),
    QgsField("second",  QVariant.Int),
    QgsField("third", QVariant.Double) ] )

raster_or = gdal.Open(RasterfilePath)

nodata = raster_or.GetRasterBand(1).GetNoDataValue()
(upper_left_x, x_size, x_rotation, upper_left_y, y_rotation, y_size) = raster_or.GetGeoTransform()

numpy_array = raster_or.ReadAsArray()

#width,height = numpy_array.shape
width=raster_or.GetRasterBand(1).XSize
height=raster_or.GetRasterBand(1).YSize

# add a feature

for row in range(height):
    features = []
    for col in range(width):
        if  (nodata == numpy_array[row,col]):
#            #Add new point:
            fet = QgsFeature()
            x = col * x_size + upper_left_x + (x_size / 2) #add half the cell size
            y = row * y_size + upper_left_y + (y_size / 2) #to centre the point
            fet.setGeometry(QgsGeometry(QgsPoint(x,y)))
            fet.initAttributes(3)
            fet.setAttribute(0, float(numpy_array[row,col]))
            fet.setAttribute(1, row)
            fet.setAttribute(2, col)
            features.append(fet)
    pr.addFeatures( [ fet] )
```